# Passing several variables from Excel to Python with XLwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I have the same question as this post but with multiple variable (and with a macro instead of a function) ([Passing a variable from Excel to Python with XLwings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167920/passing-a-variable-from-excel-to-python-with-xlwings))

I try this

```
Sub Hello ()
    Dim name,name2 As String
    RunPython ("import Test; Test.sayhi('" & Name1 & " , " & Name2 & "')")
End sub
```

But I get this error :

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: sayhi() missing  required positional arguments: 'Name2'
```

How to overcome this error plz ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string resolves to a single argument. Fix the single quotes like this:

```
RunPython ("import Test; Test.sayhi('" & Name1 & "' , '" & Name2 & "')"
```